# Action Required : Confirm your OAuth client setup by September 30th for continued access to Google APIs

Tags: google-oauth

Today I received an email with the above as subject and this in the body :

Dear Android developer,

To keep your access to Google APIs, review the OAuth client used by your Android application by September 30, 2019.

Google requires developers to [register all Android apps](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html) that request Google Account data and interact with Google APIs. The following Android package name you maintain may require the registration of an OAuth client:

com.myappname (not my real app name)

To register an OAuth client, make sure to either:

Have an existing project on Google Cloud Platform for the app you publish.

Create a new project and [configure it correctly](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849).

For the app, make sure there’s an Android OAuth client for the [package name and SHA-1 signing-certificate fingerprint](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849#installedapplications&android). If your app uses certain sensitive or restricted scopes, you’ll also need to [submit your app for verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914).

Apps without a properly registered OAuth client may not get Google Account or API data after September 30, 2019.

Thanks,
Google API team

---

I have a GCP project that has 2 OAuth 2.0 client IDs with the package name for this Android app (one Debug, one Release) and SHA1 fingerprint. Google login has been working for years with no issue. App is also verified (though we don't use any sensitive scopes). Anybody received a similar email or know what possibly might be missing?

Comment: They must've given you some links/embedded-links in this email, what are they?

Comment: I've updated the question to properly have the links

Comment: So if you believe correctly created the Android OAuth for your app (pkg/sha1), then this message could be a misfire (by an automated system), but you can reach out to either https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-dev or https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/558567 to verify.

Comment: thanks will do that. Just very surprised I seem to be the only person who got this, can't find anywhere where anybody is asking about the same thing

Comment: This mail is just a recommendation or confirmation that makes sure you did right nothing else.on the other words , you didn't do wrong .just this mail was sent to u because you are using OAuth 2.0

Answer (score 1):

This is neither a misfire or a threat. It's more of a reminder than anything else. All people who interact with Google User data get this email, and the point of this is to simply tell people "Hey, if you need to, register an OAuth client, do it by September 30th.". This is explicitly clear on the wording of the email. You can see here:

> The following Android package name you maintain may require the registration of an OAuth client

The keyword being "may". Since, from what you've posted, you already registered your client, you should be good to go. Everything beyond this:

> com.myappname (not my real app name)

Is nothing more than instructions on how to register your client. Everything above it is warning, that if you haven't, register your client. It's saying that it's possible that you haven't registered your client, so make sure you have.

Long story short, if you registered your client, you're good to go.

Comment: Hello, this doesn't explain why in the email it mentioned only one of our apps, while we have 3 that use OAuth in exactly the same way.

Comment: Go with what you know. From what we know, you've registered your client, and that should be good to go. If you haven't, register it. I'd make sure you have your settings up to date with the client, but it's possible that you're using a different email or something along those lines. I'd recommend contacting google support and asking if your client is actually registered, and if they confirm, ask about this email you were sent. I've gotten similar emails for similar things, and usually, it all works out as long as you do what's told in the email.